# Is there any way to write Unit test for a class library

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, nuget-package

I have a class library in .net core written to be a nuget package.

Is there any way to write unit test for a class library which includes some helper methods and its configuration is dependent upon the the solution in which it get installed?

Comment: Yes, create "test" solution, configure your library and execute tests

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What's your question?

Comment: My Class library just contains helper methods which is totally depandant on the solution in which it will refer.
So how can I write test on this type of library?

Comment: What kind of dependency you have, can you show an example of it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You can use NUnit to test. Code example:

Class library:

```
public class Calculator
{
    public int Add(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }

    public int Subtract(int x, int y)
    {
        return x - y;
    }
}
```

Unit test using NUnit:

```
using NUnit.Framework;

[TestFixture]
public class CalculatorTest
{
    private Calculator _cal;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _cal = new Calculator();
    }

    [Test]
    public void OnePlusOneEqualTwo()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(2, _cal.Add(1, 1));
    }

    [Test]
    public void TwoPlusTwoEqualFour()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(4, _cal.Add(2, 2));
    }

    [Test]
    public void FourPlusOneEqualFive()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(5, _cal.Add(4, 1));
    }
}
```